# AngularJS ng-if with textbox

Tags: angularjs

How to use ng-if to check when text box value?
Something like this -

```
<input type="text" ng-model="if.number" />
<div ng-if="2 + 2 === if.number">
```

Comment: change unexecutable code snippet to code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see couple issues in your code

1. non-closing div tag, so make it `<div>Content here</div>`, please
2. since `typeof(if.number) => "string"` ,and `2+2` is definitely integer - it's always false expression. so you cant compare it using ===, you should use `==`

following code works for me.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" ng-model="if.number" />
    {{if.number}}
  <div ng-if="2 + 2 == if.number">You can see me now</div>
</div>
```